# Adding 12% to multiple cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have been using a pretty simple method to add 12% to several cells and it is giving me what the percentage is not adding the 12% to the existing amounts in each cell. the method I am using is:
-12% in unused cell
-Highlight all cells that I need to add 12% too
-Paste Special
-Values
-Multiply
-OK
If someone could help me I would be grateful.

Comment: My bsic calculation would be X * 1.12 but what is yours?

Comment: If you're using _Paste Special_ then you would put `1.12` in an empty cell,  copy it, select all of your target cells, and then _Paste Special_ -> _Multiply_